# Can I have a variable number of types on Union in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-typing, pydantic

I have a structure like this:

```py
from enum import Enum

class MainEnum(str, Enum):
    A = "AA"
    B = "BB"
    ...

class ChildAEnum(str, Enum):
    C = "CC"
    D = "DD"

class ChildBEnum(str, Enum):
    E = "EE"
    F = "FF"

...

child_mapping = {
    MainEnum.A: ChildAEnum
    MainEnum.B: ChildBEnum
    ...
}
```

Where each `Enum` on the `MainEnum` has another `Enum` associated to it and indicated by the `child_mapping` map.

I want to have a `Union` typehint that can be any one of the values from `child_mapping`. I don't know if it's relevant but I'm using `pydantic` and I want this for automatic validation of the field.

Manually, it would be exactly:

```py
class Something(BaseModel):
   some_child: Union[ChildAEnum, ChildBEnum]
```

But I want to be able to just add another key-value pair to `child_mapping` and have it be automatically recognized by the `Union`.

I tried the following:

```py
class Something(BaseModel):
    some_child: Union[*list(child_mapping.values())]
```

`list(child_mapping.values())` successfully gets me a list of the types I want to use, but the unpack doesn't seem to be working

Am I even able to do this?

Comment: I think the answer is: no, you are not (sadly). Static type-checkers are unable to understand dynamically evaluated expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing about the problem helped me think about it. The solution is, instead of converting the `child_mapping.values()` to a `list`, converting it to a `tuple`.

So the solution is:

```py
class Something(BaseModel):
    some_child: Union[tuple(child_mapping.values())]
```

Comment: People should know, this *won't actually work for static analysis*, e.g. for `mypy`

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga says, no type-checker will be able to understand this kind of expression (as of August 2021), so annotating a variable in this fashion is (sadly) useless when it comes to static type-checking.

Comment: I didn't realize that. Thanks.